# How to override Google Custom Search css code, search-box height: 200px?

Tags: css, google-custom-search

I am installing a Google Custom Search into my Concrete5 based website.  It all looks great while in edit mode, but in public mode, the search box expands (stretches) to 200px in height.  I have used Developer Tools to locate the offending css code found within the linked Google CSS file listed below.  I have tried to override it without success. But also, why is this code even here? And designated as !important?  And why does it only show up when my site is public and not in Edit mode?

**Linked Google CSS file and offending code:**
https://cse.google.com/cse/style/look/v2/default.css

```
/* search box */
.gsc-search-box {
 height: 200px!important;
}
table.gsc-search-box tbody tr td * {
 height: 70%!important;
 font-size: 40px!important;
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I did Google custom search, but aren't you supposed to log into their website and generate all this code there, and specify your "Look and Feel" including height, style, etc...?

Comment: Provide a working example that demonstrates the problem... jsfiddle/codepen/snippet

Comment: if it's in an iframe, then you can't

Comment: Please share the code in which you are using it. Without look at where and what parent containers are around it and what css is being applied. We wont be able to help fully.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I thought I'd get an email when someone replied.
Anyway,
To the first reply, yes, to setup a Google custom search, you log into your Google account and access the Google Custom Search setup.  I did that,  using the "Look and Feel" options to get it to look the way I want it and then copying the code generated and pasting it into my website in the proper location.  Interestingly, it looks great while I'm in Edit mode on my Concrete5 v5.7x Theme.

Comment: The site is currently under development and so it is not publicly available.  I have a login setup that only allows viewing and no editing rights.  If I view the search box under this login, it, for some reason, appears vertically stretched.  When I use Chrome's Developer tools to look at the CSS behind the issue, it shows me that there is CSS code coming from the file "default.css" that is linked to from the url [https://cse.google.com/cse/style/look/mobile/v2/default.css].

Comment: I have discovered the offending lines of code in this CSS file are:
' /* search box */
.gsc-search-box {
 height: 200px!important;
}
table.gsc-search-box tbody tr td * {
 height: 70%!important;
 font-size: 40px!important;
}
table.gsc-search-box tbody tr td input.gsc-input {
  background-size: 50%!important;
}
'
If I disable these lines, the problem goes away.  So, I've tried to override these lines with local CSS, but can't get it to work, maybe because the settings are marked !important?
Why are these lines even in this default.css file from Google? Makes no sense!

Comment: And when I am logged in as an Admin in Edit mode, the search box looks great and the "search-box" lines of CSS code are missing from the default.css file being used which is now "default+en.css"

Comment: Here is the relative code in my site on jsfiddle for example:
[https://jsfiddle.net/e8egsevs/]

The added CSS is the code that I've located in the default.css file google links to its search code.  If you remove it, the search box displays just fine.  So, the question I have, is: How do I avoid these lines of CSS?

Comment: Here is the url to the site in question: [http://192.185.90.3/~minntronix/index.php/login]

ID: demo  PW:  review

Click on the magnifying glass icon at the right end of the menu to drop down the search box.